# LINQ to SQL Query Array in List

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, linq

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with something minor, I currently have a list of items which include an array inside the list (nothing i can do about it, data is pulled from a web API), i need to run a linq to sql query on that list to iterate through the array in that list to compare a value in the array, so for example my code would look like this:

```
var query1 = from q1 in datacontext.view
             select q1;

foreach (var item in query1)
{
    try
    {
        var query2 = from q2 in List<>
                     where q2.Array(iterate through the array to find the name)
                             .value = item.Key(is a string)
                     select q2;

        if (query2.count() == 0)
        {
            Do something
        }
        else
        {
            Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Basically whilst it's iterating through the first list to compare the value, the list in the 2nd query basically has an array inside an array and i need to find the name of the array(not the number) and compare the value of it with a value in the first query, hope that makes some sense to someone.

UPDATE: The Exact code

```
List<net.autotask.webservices4.InstalledProduct> CurrentAutotaskSoftware = GetSoftwareAlreadyInAutotask(myService);

            LANSweeperDataContext ldc = new LANSweeperDataContext();

            var licenseKey = from l in ldc.LANSweeper_License_Keys
                             select l;

            foreach (var lssi in licenseKey)
            {

                try
                {
                    var lSLicenseKeys = from c in CurrentAutotaskSoftware
                                        where c.UserDefinedFields.Any(x => x.Value == lssi.License_Key)
                                        select c;



                    if (lSLicenseKeys.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        //AddItemToAutotask(myService, lssi);
                        Console.WriteLine("Adding " + lssi.Product + lssi.License_Key); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //UpdateItemInAutotask(myService, lSLicenseKeys.First(), lssi);
                        Console.WriteLine("Updating with" + lssi.Product + lssi.License_Key);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
var hasMatch= YourList.Any(x=>x.Value==item.Key);
if(hasMatch)
{
    //Do Something
}
else
{
  //Do Something else
}
```

Comment: i worked it into the linq to sql however it doesn't enumerate the results, any ideas?

Comment: What exact problem did you face?  `from q2 in List<>`, that `List<>` comes from database or web api?

Comment: q1 is from the database and q2 is from the web api

Comment: So, what is your problem with above code? it gave some error or something?

Comment: No it works fine, however I need to encorporate it into a LINQ to SQL query because of how the rest of the code works and is required to work, after inserting it into the filter "Where YourList.Any(x=>x.Value==item.Key)" it says enumeration yielded no results

Comment: Can you update the question with full query sample where this condition needs to incorporated?

Comment: And because its an array inside an array it would need to be var hasMatch= YourList.Any(x=>x.Field.Any(y => y.Value==item.Key))

Comment: Sorry no clue what's happened there the code i updated with, haven't changed a thing and now it's working, after querying the web api again it appears as if it's added a test entry which i had added a few days ago and now it can see it it's working properly, as i said i havent changed a thing and now it's working, seriously frustrating as i've been stumped for almost 5 hours and now its suddenly working....